# Patterns for screen dynamics, GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, design-patterns, swing

I code Java/Swing based UI. My dialogs are quite complex and there are many rules for screen dynamics: when to enable/disable buttons, when to allow to edit some fields, etc.
In general there are widgets and there are some rules to set them in some state. 
I am wondering if there are any nice patterns, ideas how to resolve such problems in any standardized way.

Now I still use some flags to determine widget state etc. But with complex dialogs this approach become complicated. there is also a problem with maintenance of such code later.
I am waiting for your advices.

Regards,
Marcin

Comment: what is complex in your eyes? maybe give us a picture of one of your typical dialogs.

Comment: I cannot show you these dialogs :( but a typically dialog has a toolbar with ex. 10 buttons, some of buttons are enabled/disabled depending on user rights and another on user actions on the dialog. next there are widgets that get editable depending on results of user actions. I am just wondering if there is any pattern to track state of some widgets depending of some some criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a specific pattern fot this kind of problem, "Mediator". Is One of famous GoF design pattern

Comment: I've been using mediator back when I didn't even know it was called Mediator. It's one of those patterns that comes naturally. +1

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I am going to focus on that pattern and try use it. I will let you know.